# venv module: how to get isolation from global python Scripts directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-venv

My question concerns Python 3.10 or newer. On my Windows 10 machine, the following two directories are on the system `PATH`, placed there by the python.org installer:

```
C:\Python310\Scripts
C:\Python310
```

Now I have created and activated a virtual environment with the `venv` module:

```
py -m venv testpypi_venv
.\testpypi_venv\Scripts\activate
```

I have verified that I have isolation from site packages. As desired, `pip freeze` prints nothing, even though I have many packages installed globally.

The problem is that `venv` has not isolated me from global `Scripts`. For example, I can still run `jupyter --version` and get valid output:

```
Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 8.5.0
ipykernel        : 6.16.0
ipywidgets       : 8.0.2
jupyter_client   : 8.2.0
jupyter_core     : 5.3.0
... and so on.
```

What I expected to see was:

```
'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Does `venv` provide a way to isolate from the global python `Scripts` directory? If so, how can I do that. If not, are there any simple alternatives that I can use? I do not want to modify my global `PATH` since I want to be able to work without virtual environments for casual use.